# Icon change depending on database setting

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

for weeks now I´m trying to setup my new homepage that runs on my LAN on a raspberry pi running Raspbian.

What I want to do is save the state of some RC Switches in a database and show the actual states on my website. I´ve already set up my database, what I want now is, that icons get updated by the status of the RC switches in the databse. For example I have an icon "lightbulb_off" and "lightbulb_on". If database says light 1 is off, "lightbulb_off" shall show up.

I am at a point where everything works, but I have to reload the page everytime I clicked on an icon, what switches the RC Switch and updates the database, to see the new icon. I want the icon to change without reloading the page. 
I tried a lot to combine jscript and PHP using AJAX, but I don´t get it.

Here is my code:

```
<img id="LampTV" src=<?php Lampe($qLTV, $queryLTV); ?> onclick="Lampe('http://192.168.1.66/index.html?schalte&9'), updateStateLampeTV()">
```

So src= Lampe() reads the database for the actual state. After clicking the RC Switch switches and the database gets updated.

Now, how can I change the icon without reloading the page again? I guess it won´t work with PHP but I don´t know how to achieve it using AJAX.

Thanks for yout help!!

Update:

Now I created this function:

```
function icon(){$(document).ready(function(){$.ajax({url: 'PHP/icon_state.php',type:post',data: {'Lampe($qLTV, $queryLTV)'},success: function(data,status)
```

It shall run a function in my php file which echos a path to the correct iconfile. Doesn´t wotk this way :(

Comment: AJAX is exactly what you need. You can call a php script with AJAX that only refreshes the bit of data that you need. I don't have enough time to post an example for you but here's a [blogpost](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php) that might send you in the right direction

Comment: Well, I´ve read your blog but still I don´t get it to work...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Ajax. As I see in the comments, you tried to do something.

So, you have an id for your image, what is great. We can bind a click function to it. Pass the data what you want in the data section as an object, (or query string or array), and in the `success` function of ajax, update the source of your original image object.

```
    $('#LampTV').click(function() {
        var qLTV = 'Some data what you need to pass';
        var queryLTV = 'Some other data, what you want'
        var LampTVObj = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'PHP/icon_state.php',
            data: {
                qLTV: qLTV,
                queryLTV: queryLTV
            }, success: function(data) {
                //In your php you need to echo the URL of the status image
                //like this 
                //echo 'http://example.com/images/online.png';
                $(LampTVObj).attr('src', data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Never *ever* suggest `async: false`. That leads to far more problems than it solves (and locks up the browser while the request is occurring). Always recommend working *with* the async nature of browsers.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie You are right, sorry, I've fixed that.

Comment: `async: true` is the default. Just rip it out.

Comment: Wow, a big step forwards!! Wouldn´t get it to work without this example, so thank you so far! But still one problem: I use Firebug in Firefox and I can see, that the file "icon_state.php" is executed up to 6 times, what makes the icon switch very fast and not deliver the correct image. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I don't know, maybe you print 6 times the source of the image in your PHP file.

Comment: I recognized it´s incremented by 1 somehow, it starts with 2 times executing "icon_state.php" and increments on every click. So on the second click "ichon_state.php" is executed 3 times, then 4 times and so on... I just run a function one time inside the "icon_state.php" file, so could it be something else? I am so close to finish that ass pain thing now...

Comment: I also must mention, that it only works on the second click on the icon! "icon_state.php" will not get executed when I click the icon the first time.

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes I created a new file "test.php". Here is the code of that file:

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Home-Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design.css">
</head>

<body>
<!--Script Bereich-->
<script>
//Funktion für Lampen
function change_state(){
$('#LampTV').click(function() {
        var LampTVObj = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'PHP/updateStateLampeTV.php',
            success: function(data) {
                //In your php you need to echo the URL of the status image
                //like this 
                //echo 'http://example.com/images/online.png';
                $(LampTVObj).attr('src', data);
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
}
</script>
<!--Script Bereich ENDE-->
<?php
include ("PHP/icon_state.php");
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE); 



?>
<img id="LampTV" src="<?php Lampe($qLTV, $queryLTV); ?>" onclick='change_state()'>
</body>
</html>
```

and here we have the 'updateStateLampeTV.php' file:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);

    // Connect to MySQL
    include("dbconnect.php");
    //Funktion zur Abfrage des aktuellem Zustandes in der Datenbank 

    // Datenbank auswählen
    mysql_select_db("homecontrol") or die(mysql_error());

// SQL-Query
    $queryLTV = "SELECT Zustand FROM `funksteckdosen` WHERE Standort= 'Lampe TV'";
// Query ausführen (die Datensatzgruppe $rs enthält das Ergebnis)
    $qLTV = mysql_query($queryLTV);
//Status Lampe
    function statusLampe(){
    global $queryLTV;
    global $qLTV;

        while ($datensatz = mysql_fetch_assoc($qLTV)){
    $z = $datensatz['Zustand'];
    }
    if ($z == "An"){
        $SQL = "UPDATE funksteckdosen SET Zustand = 'Aus' WHERE `funksteckdosen`.`Standort` = 'Lampe TV'";    
        // Execute SQL statement
        mysql_query($SQL);
        echo "../gfx/ligthbulb_on.png";
    }
        elseif($z == "Aus"){
        $SQL = "UPDATE funksteckdosen SET Zustand = 'An' WHERE `funksteckdosen`.`Standort` = 'Lampe TV'";    
        // Execute SQL statement
        mysql_query($SQL);
        echo "../gfx/ligthbulb_off.png";
        }
    }
statusLampe();
?>
```

Don´t look at my comments, they are german...

Well, when I click on the icon the first time nothing happens, on the second click Firebug tells me 2 times "`POST http://myIP/PHP/updateStateLampeTV.php`" (I must mention that "updateStateLampeTV.php = icon_state.php with different echoes). On the next click it´s sent 3 times and so on. Do you see where the error is?